# How to add one to a field in my object from radio button on submit

Tags: javascript, mysql, vue.js

I have this voting web app I am building, I need to take a value from when my radio button is checked for a particular cantidate and add it to my database, but for mow I am using an object has my database and I will like to add one to the vote_count of any candidate selected when the submit vote button is clicked.

```
    <div class="container">

    <div>

      <form id="the-form" action="#">
        <h1 class="text-center">{{Title}}</h1>
        <div v-for="(candidate) in candidates" :key="candidate.topic_id">
         <label>
        <input type="radio" class="option-input radio" value="1" id="radio" name="example" />
        {{candidate.candidate_name}}
        </label>
        </div> 
        <b-button href="#" class= "btn" variant="primary" router-link to="/votingpage">
                     Submit Vote</b-button>
      </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        selected: [], // Must be an array reference!
        Title: 'Providence Class Captain Election',
        candidates: [
            //  {
            //    Title: 'Providence Class Captain'
            //    },
            {
                candidate_name: 'Babangida', 
                candidate_party: 'pdp', 
                vote_count: 0,
                vote_id:'1'
                },

            {
                candidate_name: 'Rochas', 
                candidate_party: 'Anpp', 
                vote_count: 0,
                vote_id:'2'
                },
            {
                candidate_name: 'Ajimobi', 
                candidate_party: 'Apc', 
                vote_count: 0,
                vote_id:'3'
                },
            {
                candidate_name: 'Buhari', 
                candidate_party: 'Apc', 
                vote_count: 0,
                vote_id:'4'
                }

        ]
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think the number of candidates can be the vote count, no need to keep it with every object. Or you have any use case for it?

Comment: id to the input type radio should be unique, it messes with the DOM element. It is not going to solve your problem but will eliminate future issues.

Comment: I want to count vote for every different candidate differently

Comment: how do i change the id.. since I am using for to loop through